# How to pass a variable for Current date folder in put command in snowflake

Tags: shell, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've set the variable for current month & year for 202108 like

```
SET folder = TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYYMM')
```

Now I've to pass that variable in PUT command in snowflake from snowsql.

Where the cmd looks like

```
put file:///folder1/folder2/"$folder = 202108"/file.txt @stage/schema/folder auto_compress = false;
```

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks,
Pavan Kumar

Comment: Do you see error with this command with variable replacement?

Comment: Yes. It's giving error like files doesn't exist. But the path i've given is correct.

Comment: In put command "$folder= 202108" i've given here for understanding. Originally it's $folder